# Log long running queries in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I would like to log, to Serilog, any Entity Framework Core query/command which takes longer than 1 second to run.  Ideally I would like to log the generated SQL and how long it took to run.

Would welcome any thoughts on how best to achieve this.  I am using EF Core 2.1.